# How do I delete my number from iMessage on send and receive from my iMac?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, messages

When I go to settings, iMessage does not show up under anything and I cannot access iMessage settings straight from the iMessage icon. Please help! There was a previous answer that said you could press command and comma, but when I press this, I get this picture.
[image]

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: You should try pressing command+comma when the iMessage app is active (i.e. the program names shows in the top left part of the menu bar). Now you have opened your Firefox preferences...

Comment: @BartArondson correct answer, you might want to put it as an answer :)

Comment: But shouldn't the question be "How to detect in which Application I am?" :) ?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that iMessage is the active application, i.e. the word iMessage shows on the top left in your menu bar.
Then press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to access the preferences.

This works for most apps, in your question you demonstrate this for Firefox.